# lucene port stemmer not working with query parser

Tags: java, lucene

i have been trying to use port stemmer for singular and plural in lucene 6.2.0
my code is as follows

```
         Builder q = new PhraseQuery.Builder();
         PorterStemmer stemmer = new PorterStemmer();
         for(String term : terms){
             System.out.println("search term---"+term);
            stemmer.setCurrent(term);
            String termss = stemmer.getCurrent();
             q.add(new Term("name",termss));
         }
         q.setSlop(terms.length * 0);
         Query r=  q.build();
         QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("name", analyzer);
         r=  parser.parse(QueryParser.escape(query));
```

so if i search for **cats** the stemmed term comes out to be **cat** which  is fine but i still get **zero hits**
**but if i remove the queryparser i get the correct answer**
Can anyone explain me why is this happening and how i can still retain queryparser with port stemmer?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. The first 10 lines build a query, `r`, then in the last line, you get rid of that query and replace it with the output from the QueryParser, based on some previously unknown variable `query`. What is `query`, and what is the point of those first 10 lines of code?

Comment: Direct answer on how to use a stemmer with QueryParser, by the way, is to use an analyzer with a stemmer. `EnglishAnalyzer`, for one example.